# Can I perform compute on an NVMe storage device?

Tags: low-level, nvme

I'll start by saying this is not something I am doing in a production system, just a personal project and just writing coding to learn and try and find challenging tasks.

So NVMe drives are used in computers for storing information and they have controllers and perform a set of standard operations and I have been reading through the specification (https://nvmexpress.org/developers/) trying to figure out if there is any way to use them in a way that would actually be getting them to compute information. I have been reading through the specifications, and there are a lot of different commands they can do. But I haven't found anything where someone has already tried this yet, but maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms.
I wanted to check if anyone knows if this is something that has been done, using NVMe storage as a compute device?

Some of the things I thought I might be able to find where?

- Maybe a write option equivalent to a logical OR where it would write 1s over 0s but not change other values?
- Maybe a way to compare values as they were overwritten, so if there was a status code that was tracking wear levelling or if the data actually changed on a write, then it might have been possible to know if the value written to was already set to the value I just wrote?
- Maybe a check if data is blank or all zeros command?
- Maybe a command to return the hash or parity bit for the data instead of the data?
- I was hoping to find some combination or Move or BitShift or Logical operators that
  be chained together to do calculations on data without returning it.
- Or possibly a status code on an operation that would give me information about the data.

Comment: IIRC, physical NAND flash reads as `1` in the erased state, and can be written to `0`.  But inversion is basically free in hardware if it's hard-wired in so a drive could in theory support either of setting more bits or clearing more bits for already-written sectors without an erase.  (I think.)  In practice I'd guess that NVMe doesn't have a command for that.

Comment: Interesting ideas about what *could* be possible.  Copying within the drive without sending data over the PCIe bus might get used, but I doubt there'd be much real-world use for shift or bitwise booleans; XOR en/decryption doesn't get much use.  You could imagine a command that lets you upload blocks to be used for XOR-and-copy do decrypting with a stream cipher (like RC5) only requires CPU->device transfers of the stream data, not read/CPU xor/write.  But stream ciphers are *not* widely used.  Now if there was a built-in AES that would be another matter.  But most use cases aren't disk->disk

Comment: So the compute command ideas seem unlikely to find much use, but checking for all zero, or for some hash of the data, might get use to save PCIe and main-memory bandwidth.  (In some hypothetical command set that had this, assuming NVMe doesn't.)

Comment: I wouldn't be impressed if it is impossible. Like other host-to-drive interfaces, NVMe is designed the way that host "thinks" how to parallel data, etc, and the drive is "dumb".

Comment: Did some more research, at the moment I think the answer is NO.
But there is a draft standard for "Computational Storage" and a Technical Working Group for it (https://www.snia.org/computational). 
So maybe in a few years.

Comment: I said earlier that NAND flash could in theory allow setting or clearing more bits without erasing.  But it's only that simple for SLC flash that store 1 bit per cell.  MLC / TLC / QLC that encode 4, 8, or 16 different levels in a single cell, not just on/off, map multiple logical bits to the same physical cell, and even if they could move from one level to a higher level (not sure), that wouldn't always correlate with setting some previously unset bits.  Plus there's probably some error-correction coding per write-block that makes it not that simple even for SLC.